# CA2000 warning on returned value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, return-value, static-analysis, ca2000

I know this has been discussed many times but no solutions seems to work so I thought and may be worth a try to reopen it since some time has passed.

I have a function:

```
Public Function Test() As Object
    Dim retVal As DisposableObject
    Dim tempRetVal As DisposableObject
    Try
        tempRetVal = New DisposableObject
        retVal = tempRetVal
        tempRetVal = Nothing
        Return retVal
    Catch
        tempRetVal.Dispose()
        Throw
    Finally
        tempRetVal.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

As you can see, there are a lot of Dispose statements. This is because I was trying to find a way to have it working. The only way I found (which clearly is not a solution) was to add `retVal.Dispose()` before returning retval.

```
 Public Function Test() As Object
    Dim retVal As DisposableObject
    Dim tempRetVal As DisposableObject
    Try
        tempRetVal = New DisposableObject
        retVal = tempRetVal
        tempRetVal = Nothing
        retVal.Dispose()
        Return retVal
    Catch
        tempRetVal.Dispose()
        Throw
    Finally
        tempRetVal.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Any hint will be gladly appreciated! :)

Note: I'm using VS2012

**EDIT:**
I also tried the simple template proposed by MS and it doesn't work either:

```
Public Function Test() As Object
    Dim retVal As DisposableObject
    Dim tempRetVal As DisposableObject
    Try
        tempRetVal = New DisposableObject
        retVal = tempRetVal
        tempRetVal = Nothing
        Return retVal
    Finally
        if tempRetVal isnot Nothing then tempRetVal.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

CA2000 is thrown on `tempRetVal = New DisposableObject`.

Comment: Looks like a `FxCop` warning message.

Comment: Yes it is. FxCop has been included in VS from 2010 and in 2008 as an add-on if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only way I found (which clearly is not a solution) was to add
>   retVal.Dispose() before returning retval.

Why? You anyways have a `finally` block defined. Let the finally block take care of the disposal. Your code should look like below. Also,

```
 Public Function Test() As Object
    Dim retVal As LLServerConnection
    Dim tempRetVal As LLServerConnection
    Try
        tempRetVal = New LLServerConnection
        retVal = tempRetVal
        tempRetVal = Nothing
        Return retVal
    Catch
        Throw
    Finally
        If Not tempRetVal Is Nothing Then
        tempRetVal.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

See [CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx) for more information.

**EDIT:**

To my believe, you are getting that CA2000 warning message because of the `return` statement inside `TRY` block. Rather, `return` the obejct before your subroutine actually end. See below code with comment added to the changes. This will be fine now.

```
Public Function Test() As DisposableObject //Change object to actual type DisposableObject
    Dim retVal As DisposableObject = Nothing
    Dim tempRetVal As DisposableObject = Nothing

    Try
        tempRetVal = New DisposableObject()
        retVal = tempRetVal
        tempRetVal = Nothing

    Finally
      If Not tempRetVal Is Nothing Then
         tempRetVal.Dispose()
      End If 

    End Try

        Return retVal //Return the object before your subroutine ends

End Function
```

Comment: You're right, in my tests, I tried removing every condition to see if it would change something and forgot to put it back before posting. I agree that my code should look something like this and in fact, I tried it but it still give a CA2000 warning/error.

Comment: That's strange. If this is what exactly your code have then Per MSDN it shouldn't through CA2000 any more. Another thought would be removing that empty catch altogether and just have `try .. finally`. see how that works.

Comment: As explained in the Edit, I tried it but the message is still there. Something seems to be wrong in the way static analysis detects lost of sight when a value is returned.